# sth wrong when i use jsx in vue's script tag

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, jsx, tsx

**here is my .vue component**

```
<script lang="tsx" setup>
  import { useLoadData } from '@/views/hooks/dict'
  import { computed, useAttrs, useSlots } from 'vue'
  const props = defineProps({
    code: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    plain: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number, Array, Object],
      default: '',
    },
  })
  const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
  const attrs: any = useAttrs()
  const slots: any = useSlots()
  const { dictData, formatter } = useLoadData(props.code)
  const optArr: any = computed(() => {
    return dictData.value
  })
  const Render = () => {
    if (props.plain) {
      return <span>{formatter(props.modelValue)}</span>
    }
    const slotContent: any = {
      default: () => {
        return slots.default
          ? slots.default()
          : optArr.value.map((item: { code: string; name: string }) => {
              return (
                <el-option
                  value={item.code}
                  label={item.name}
                  key={item.code}
                ></el-option>
              )
            })
      },
    }
    if (slots.prefix) {
      slotContent['prefix'] = () => slots.prefix()
    }
    if (slots.empty) {
      slotContent['empty'] = () => slots.empty()
    }
    return (
      <el-select
        modelValue={props.modelValue}
        filterable
        style="width: 100%"
        onUpdate:modelValue={(value: any) => {
          emit('update:modelValue', value)
        }}
        {...attrs}
      >
        {slotContent}
      </el-select>
    )
  }
</script>
<template>
  <Render />
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

**here is the tips that vscode show **
"Property 'el-option' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'"
and
"'el-option' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type '"el-option"' is not a valid JSX element type."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGks5.png)

Is anyone know how to solve this tips